# How to manage the display of a multiple value field in a individualy way?

Tags: entities, display-suite

I have a content type with a field called "anotations" which is set to have 2 values.

Im using display suite,then in `admin/structure/types/manage/mycontenttype/display` I'd like to show the 1st value of the "anotation" field in the "header" region and the 2nd value of the "anotation" field in the footer.

Is there any way to do this?

Just in case someone wonders why do I need to do this: I'm just trying to avoid to create new fields as much as I can, since I noticed that having too much fields affect the general performance of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this creating [Dynamics Fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/1795314#dynamicfield) with the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views, comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7 only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!
>
> By defining custom view modes (build modes in D6), you can define how one piece of content should be displayed in different places such as teaser lists, search results, the full node, views etc.